# How i create same drop down in my custom module

Tags: magento2, email

how i add this type of drop down in system.xml
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For custom DropDown follow Below setps:**

To add a dropdown field with specific options in the `system.xml` file in Magento 2, you can use the `<source_model>` element to specify a model that provides the options for the dropdown. Here's an example of how you can add a dropdown field with options in your `system.xm`l file:

```
<field id="my_dropdown_field" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>My Dropdown Field</label>
    <source_model>Custommodule\MyModule\Model\Config\Source\MyOptions</source_model>
</field>
```

In the example above, we added a field with the ID `my_dropdown_field`. Here are the attributes and elements used:

- `translate="label"`: Enables translation for the field label.
- `type="select"`: Specifies that the field should be a dropdown.
- `sortOrder="10"`: Defines the order in which the field appears relative to other fields.
- `showInDefault, showInWebsite, showInStore`: Determines the visibility of the field in different configuration scopes.

The `<source_model>` element specifies the model that provides the options for the dropdown. In this example, we used `Custommodule\MyModule\Model\Config\Source\MyOptions` as the source model. You will need to create this model and implement the logic to provide the available options.

Here's an example implementation of the source model:

```
<?php
namespace Custommodule\MyModule\Model\Config\Source;

class MyOptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 'option1',
                'label' => __('Option 1')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'option2',
                'label' => __('Option 2')
            ],
            // Add more options as needed
        ];
    }
}
```

In the `toOptionArray()` method, you can return an array of options, where each option is represented by a nested array containing value and label keys. Adjust the options and their labels according to your requirements.

Once you have defined the source model and added the field to the `system.xml` file, you should see the dropdown field with the specified options in the configuration settings.

**For Email Sender Field follow the below steps:**

Add in your `system.xml` file

```
<field id="email_sender" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
  <label>Email Sender</label>
  <comment>Select for Email Sender</comment>
  <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity
   </source_model>
</field>
```

**Note**: For Your custom field for dropdown you can use above example But You need to use Magento default drop down then just change path on <source_model> and use default Model for the option No need to create it again in your custom Module.

Comment: For the specific options asked in the question `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity` may be used as source_model.

Comment: yes, @Daniel you are right..!! for specific options used `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity` as `source_model`

Comment: @Daniel You can check Ronak Ans it is correct.

Comment: @Himanshu I am aware of that. I just think this is the much better, detailed answer and the information about the source model that was asked for would improve it to exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add the source model of your custom field.**

```
<field id="email_sender" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Email Sender</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

system.xml:

```
<field id="list_mode" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>List Mode</label>        
   <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListMode</source_model>
</field>
```

and Make a class like this:

**Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListMode.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class ListMode implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
 public function toOptionArray()
 {
  return [
    ['value' => 'grid', 'label' => __('Grid Only')],
    ['value' => 'list', 'label' => __('List Only')],
    ['value' => 'grid-list', 'label' => __('Grid (default) / List')],
    ['value' => 'list-grid', 'label' => __('List (default) / Grid')]
  ];
 }
}
```